# How can I ignore tests when under a particular browser?

Tags: cucumber, selenium-webdriver, capybara

My suite of cucumbers gets run on both Firefox and Chrome.  Some of them require a browser resize, which is horrible to deal with in Chrome.  Since the behaviors that need the resize don't require cross browser testing, I'd like some way to ignore them when the detected browser is Chrome.   Is there a way to do this?  Perhaps with hooks or in the steps? I'm currently doing the resizing in Before and After hooks.

Comment: There's no code that is problematic or indicative of what I need to do.  I need to know if there is a pattern to accomplish this. I don't even need implementation, just ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which web-driver you are using, but for watir-webdriver you can do the following:

You can determine which browser it is in the steps that you want to skip using the code in the below URL.

http://watirwebdriver.com/determining-which-browser/

Once you determine that it is chrome you can just skip that particular step.

Answer (score 0):

In your test helper, you can add those methods :

```
def use_chrome_driver
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
  end
  Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome
end

def setup
  Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
end
```

All your tests will use the selenium default webdriver, then when you need to use Chrome, just call the method use_chrome_driver at the beginning of your test like that :

```
def test_login_with_chrome
  use_chrome_driver
  ...
end
```

You may also add into your helper your firefox driver with the correct browser size you need, and make it the default selenium browser.